# How to execute an external process in VisualWorks?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

How do you execute an external process in VisualWorks Smalltalk?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExternalProcess fork`. e.g. `ExternalProcess fork: 'date'.`.

However, `fork` will only take one program and the arguments have to be passed separately in an array. If you want a more complex command you can use the `shOne:` method: `ExternalProcess  shOne: 'test -d data || mkdir data && cd data'.`