# Execute shell script from Smalltalk VisualWorks UI

Tags: shell, smalltalk

I am developing a UI in Smalltalk , and when I click one button I need to execute a shell script , that will execute a C++ application.

The reason I'm doing this is that I coded my application in C++ for a project, then I was told that this application needed an UI and that the UI has to be in Smalltalk so it can be included in a bigger UI coded in smalltalk, but since I can't code it again to be entirely in Smalltalk i figured I'll just call a script.

I saw that we can use shOne to run an external process, but can we do the same for a script?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969727/how-to-execute-an-external-process-in-visualworks

Comment: to run script ~> `sh ./script`

Comment: That is what I was referring to but can we write something like : `"ExternalProcess fork: 'sh ./script' ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes shOne: can be used to run a script. The difference between doing an shOne: and a fork: is exactly that shOne: uses the shell (and waits for the result, and fork: gives you more control over some of the options).